# Which facebook SDK to use with Xamarin.Android?

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

There appears to be two obvious ways to integrate facebook into an Xamarin.Android app.

One is to use the bindings project at: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Facebook

And the other is to use the Xamarin Component at https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk

Can anyone give the pros and cons for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with the Outercurve component in the Component store https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebook-sdk after reading the VSM article http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2014/07/01/Be-More-Social.aspx

Comment: it seems like that it does a web view request, not calling facebook app, is it?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot remember as this was some time ago. But it is likely, and certainly for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use the Component from Xamarin, because of the better support, ease of use & cross platform compatibility. All xamarin components come with samples and tutorials for each platform, which make them easier to implement.

[Facebook SDK : Xamarin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebook-sdk)